# "Failed to load resources from file. Please check setup" in Net.1.1 on Windows 10

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a .NET application running on a client computer using Windows 10 Home 2017, version 1703, build 15063.250.

The application is a Windows Form Application developed under .NET 1.1.
I have the .Net 1.1 successfully installed on the computer.

When I run the application I get a simple message box with the error:

> Failed to load resources from file. Please check setup.

There is no entry on the Event Viewer.

The error only happens on computers running this specific windows version.
I already searched the web for this issue but I didn’t found a useful answer.

Comment: Why are you targeting .NET 1.1, it is extremely old. there is no version of windows out there that does not come with at least 2.0 bundled in.

Comment: The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2. Support for .NET 1.1 ended over 10 years ago

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos one correction is that .NET 1.1 support only expired on July 14, 2015, so not "10 years ago". Besides, .NET 3.5.1 is still supported.

Comment: @LexLi that's not correct. Support as in "limited life support" was available only for those OSs that had .NET 1.1 preinstalled, which is Windows XP and 2003. For every other OS, real support ended when .NET 2.0 came out. The same holds for 3.5.1 - it only has limited support through the OSs where it came preinstalled.

Comment: @LexLi even *that* support may not mean much - TLS 1.2 was added in .NET 4.5.2 You can't make a call to GMail or any other service that requires TLS1.2 from any earlier version. Even if you have an OS that offers "support" for an obsolete .NET version, you may not be able to use it for long

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I worked for Microsoft before, so I could not interpret the [FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17455/lifecycle-faq-net-framework) in your way, and "limited life support" is never a Microsoft term. Different from IE, which requires you to always use the latest on a specific OS, .NET Framework users can keep using .NET 3.5.1 and receive full support (mainstream or extended based on the Windows version).  TLS is supported by .NET 3.5.1 if the underlying OS supports that. That's a design limitation, as older Windows releases won't support something coming in 2008.

Comment: @LexLi you misunderstood. Limited life support as in a vegetative state, hooked to a respirator of a county hospital. Yes, as long as you pay the respirator stays on. Microsoft Services may have no problem with charging support dollars to keep this up, but it's not a situation that any developer would want to find himself in.

Comment: @LexiLi As for TLS **1.2** it was never supported in any version before 4.5.2. The *enum* option was added in 4.5.2. Nowadays though a lot of companies demand *nothing less* than TLS 1.2 - Google, GDSs like Sabre, airlines banks, government services. TLS 1.0 itself is already considered obsolete. If you insist on remaining on an obsolete .NET runtime version, be prepared to get into trouble

Comment: @LexiLi as for "mainstream or extended support" you probably misunderstand the FAQ, or at least you apply a Microsoft Services-centric meaning to it. That phrase means that if something breaks, Microsoft will fix as long as you pay a support contract, it but nothing else. What developers mean by support is new libraries that target the runtime, upgrades and features to existing libraries and support from OSS projects. None of these exists for 3.5.1 any more

Comment: @LexiLi finally, important OSS projects like Dapper and Automapper have already started abandoning runtimes less than 4.0.

Comment: It is so typical SO, to actually allow debate on whether a user should not use .NET 1.1. anymore, instead of helping him out. Now, I have the exact same issue with an ancient custom made application. Customer does not want to upgrade for various reasons (mostly money), so we are doing what we can to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it looks like Creators update did some stuff to how .NET 1.1 works. I have an application that runs fine on 14393 (Anniversary update). In Creators update version (15063) it fails with exact same error.

But, the application can still be run as Domain or local admin account. Hence, it must be some security issue.

**EDIT (POSSIBLE ANSWER)**

I have located and fixed the error in my project.

The error means there is StackOverflowException in your code. Yeah, I know.

In my project it was this piece of code:

```
public object GetValue(string someParam) {
    try {
        return GetValueEx(someParam).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Method `GetValueEx` returns `object`.

Now, the problem was, that `GetValueEx` returned null and for some odd reason on Windows 10 Creators update this will not just throw `NullReferenceException`, but would start bubbling and bubbling until `StackOverflowException` would be thrown.

In earlier versions of Windows OS, this works without a glitch.

I fixed this code snippet to:

```
public object GetValue(string someParam) {
    try {
        object result = GetValueEx(someParam);
        return (null == result) ? result : result.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

just do a MessageBox.Show in all your catch loops and play your code in a NON Windows 10 OS.
You will see a NullReferenceException.
Modify your code to avoid this exception, then it will work in your Windows 10 OS up to date with Creator update.